# Can an overloaded member function of a class depend on the outcome of an overloaded constructor of that class?

Tags: c++, overloading, constructor-overloading

I have a class with an overloaded constructor where each version of the constructor initializes a different set of private attributes for that class. I also have a public member function of that class that will perform some operation based on the private attributes of that class. I want to overload the member function so that when I call it from the main function, it will execute an operation and return a value. Each operation will be different based on the exact outcome of the corresponding constructor. Is this possible? How could I implement this in C++? This is some incorrect code trying to express the idea:

```
class someClass {
    
    double var1, var2, var3, var4, var5;

    public:
    someClass(double in1) {
        // operations that initialize var1
    }

    someClass(double in1, double in2) {
        // operations that initialize var1 and var2
    }

    someClass(double in1, double in2, double in3) {
        // operations that initialize var1, var2 and var3
    }

    someClass(double in1, double in2, double in3, double in4) {
        // operations that initialize var1, var2, var3 and var4
    }

    someClass(double in1, double in2, double in3, double in4, double in5) {
        // operations that initialize var1, var2, var3, var4 and var5
    }


    double calcVal() {
        return in1 + in3;
        // this one is executed if the 1st constructor was called
    }

    double calcVal() {
        return in1 + in2;
        // this one is executed if the 2nd constructor was called
    }

    double calcVal() {
        return in1 + in2 + in3;
        // this one is executed if the 3rd constructor was called
    }

    double calcVal() {
        return in1 + in2 + in3 + in4;
        // this one is executed if the 4th constructor was called
    }

    double calcVal() {
        return in1 + in2 + in3 + in4 + in5;
        // this one is executed if the 5th constructor was called
    }
}
```

Comment: No, your function cannot know which constructor was used to create the object. And in this case it would be a lot simpler to just have a `std::vector<double>` member instead and have your function return the sum of all the elements instead

Comment: Also `return in1 + in3;` would be a big problem if your first constructor is used, since it only initializes `in1`

Comment: `Each operation will be different based on the exact outcome of the corresponding constructor` So just make different classes.

Comment: @UnholySheep: Even a little worse.... it initialized `var1`, left `var2` through `var5` indeterminate, and `in1` went out of scope.  There never was an `in3`.

Comment: @UnholySheep or even simpler, get rid of the `vector`, and calculate the `double` as needed right in the constructor, and then have the function simply return that `double`

Comment: In this specific case there seems little benefit in not calculating the sum in the constructor, e.g. `template<class ...Args> someClass(Args...args): val1((args + ...)){}` and simply ever having a single member variable that is returned by the function. Of course your real scenario is probably more complex, but the best approaches I can think of here are using `std::optional` or creating separate member functions and additionally storing a member function pointer in an additional member variable... Both are suboptimal performance-wise

Comment: The operations aren't representative of what I want to do, it's just some random thing I plugged in here to get the idea of the structure im aiming for across.

Comment: I'm with @KamilCuk It really sounds like this should be a factory class that returns different subclasses depending on how you call the constructor. And then each subclass can implement its own `calcVal()`. The whole point of object-oriented programming is to avoid contructions like you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this looks like inheritance with a virtual function.

```
struct someClass {
     virtual ~someClass() {}
     virtual double calcVal() = 0;
};

struct classWithVar1 : someClass {
    double var1;
    classWithVar1(double in1) : var1(in1) {}
    double calcVal() override { return var1; }
};

struct classWithVar2 : someClass {
    double var1, var2;
    classWithVar2(double in1, double in2) : var1(in1), var2(in2) {}
    double calcVal() override { return var1 + var2; }
};

/* etc. */
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I get want you want, but from how you describe it, you can simply assign some enum depending on the called constructor. And then test it in the `calcVal()` member function:

```
class someClass {
    enum class constr { cons1, cons2, cons3, cons4, cons5 };
    double var1, var2, var3, var4, var5;
    constr c;
 
    public:
    someClass(double in1) {
       c = constr::cons1; // and initialisation, of course...
    }

    someClass(double in1, double in2) {
        c = constr::cons2; // more here
    }

    someClass(double in1, double in2, double in3) {
        c = constr::cons3; // more here
    }

    someClass(double in1, double in2, double in3, double in4) {
        c = constr::cons4; // more here
    }

    someClass(double in1, double in2, double in3, double in4, double in5) {
        c = constr::cons5; // more here
    }


    double calcVal() {
        switch(c)
        { 
           case constr::cons1:  return var1 + var3;
           case constr::cons2:  return var1 + var2;
        // you get the idea...
        }
    }
}
```